# Retracting a punctured cell in a CW-complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, cw-complexes

In the proof of the cellular approximation theorem, [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) use the facts that if $Y$ is a CW-complex and $\ast$ is a point in an open $k$-cell $e^k$, then $Y-\ast$ deformation retracts into $Y-\overline{e^k}$, but he doesn't go into details. Clearly, the idea must be using the following retraction:
$$r:D^k-\left\{\Phi^{-1}(\ast)\right\}\to \partial D^k$$
Where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the restriction of the characteristic map to the open disk. I would like to define the retraction:

$$\rho:Y-\ast \to Y-\overline{e^k}, \ \ \ y\mapsto \begin{cases}y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if  $\ \ y\in Y-e^k$} \\ \Phi(r(\Phi^{-1}(y))) \ \ \ \text{if  $\ \ y\in e^k-\ast$} \end{cases}$$

But, I don't know how to prove that this map is continous. I can't apply gluing lemma because $Y-e^k$ is closed and $e^k-\ast$ is open in $Y-\ast$. Moreover $Y-\ast$ is not a CW-complex in a canonical way (at least not in a way that I know).

Comment: Why not use the gluing lemma on $\overline{e^k}\setminus\ast$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, how do you prove that the restriction of $\rho$ to the punctured close cell is continous?

Comment: The gluing lemma doesn’t need you to be working on a cell complex.  After some mild conditions, all you need are two maps that cover your space and agree on their overlap.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, but I don't see how to prove that $\rho$ is continous on $\overline{e^k}-\ast$

Comment: It may not be a CW complex, but these things still carry the subspace topologies. Spell out these definitions to answer your question.

Comment: @Tyrone I tried to, but I didn't manage.

Comment: In the construction of a cell complex, you take a quotient of a disjoint union.  $\Phi$ is a bijection on part of this disjoint union, so you get some of the continuity from there.

Comment: $A\subseteq(Y-\ast)$ is closed (open) iff there is a closed (open) $\widetilde A\subseteq Y$ such that $A=\widetilde A\cap(Y-\ast)=\widetilde A-\ast$. Of course $\widetilde A$ is closed (open) iff $\widetilde A\cap \overline e$ is closed (open) in $\overline e$ for each cell $e\subseteq Y$. Thus $A$ is closed (open) iff $A\cap\overline e$ is closed (open) in $\overline e$ for each cell $e\neq e^k$ and if $A\cap(\overline e^k-\ast)$ is closed (open) in $\overline e^k-\ast$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(D^k - \Phi^{-1}(*)) \sqcup (Y - e^k) @>>> S^{k-1} \sqcup (Y - e^k) \\
@V\Phi VV @VV\phi V\\
Y - * @>>>Y - e^k \\
\end{CD}
$$
the top map is continuous by the gluing lemma, and the vertical maps are quotient maps (you only need to check that the left one is a quotient map). Since there is a set map filling the square it is continuous by the universal property of the quotient.